# Handling Ajax Form Validation with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So this is going to sound like a very noob question but I am just beginning with ajax and need some help.

When an Ajax post sends values to a PHP script for validation and the validation fails, due to say an invalid password, must that PHP script then post back the values of the error messages with another ajax post?

---

Okay I think I phrased this question very incorrectly so I am just updating it to make it more understandable.

I have a wordpress plugin which creates a contact form and then validates all the data through javascript before making an ajax post to a separate PHP script for validation. What I seem to be not understanding is if the data fails validation in the PHP script, how then do I post back to the main page with error messages?

Comment: Ajax is just a request which is answered by a response. the response can eiter be a OK, or the Error message(s). either as html/text or as json object. depends on your implementation.

Comment: if you were using jquery ajax, you can get the result after your post, now whatever return your php has it doesn't matter cos ajax would return it btw.

Comment: The last part of the question doesn't make any sense.  If the AJAX post to the PHP code isn't valid, the PHP code can simply respond with an error indicating this.  The client-side code would receive that response from the request and handle it accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "must that PHP script then post back the values of the error messages with another ajax post?" Whenever you perform an AJAX [request] the php script should provide a [response] that might be either a confirmation or an error. That's up to you to decide, I'm just not getting the question :P

Comment: What I mean is that should the client side validation pass, the ajax post then sends those inputted values (say an email and name) to a PHP script for server side validation. Should the server side validation pass then the details will be emailed no problem, however if the server side validation fails I then need some way to post back to the page and inform the user why their data did not pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some kind of HTTP response.

That response won't be very useful if it doesn't tell the client what the errors with the request were.

There's nothing Ajaxy about the response as far as PHP is concerned, it is just a standard HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

For sure php should return a json response to the client.

You can place the messages in the response

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("valid" => false, "message" => "Invalid User")); ?>
```

or just place status codes and have the client side handle the error messages.

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("valid" => false)); ?>

<script>

   // I'm using jQuery here

   ...

   function(result) {

      var response = $.parseJSON(result);

      if(!response.valid){alert('Invalid User')}

   }

</script>
```